# ASP.Net error messages file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I receive an  error messages from a request I make 
for example

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client ...

I want to parse this error and others like into some sort of grouping for loggin purposes  , Is there a resource file for ASP.Net error message that i can look at all possible error message formats?

Comment: You're asking for all possible values for `Request.Path` that might give you that error? I doubt such a thing exists. But .NET source code is available for you to dig through.

Comment: Why do you need all the possible errors listing ? Grouping your application errors by error message, from time to time, and logging them (or even storing them into a database, where statistical manipulation may be easier/trivial) will not do it ?

Comment: If you're looking to log errors and have them nicely formatted, as well was easily accessible, I highly recommend [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/). Quote from the page, "ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and Handlers) is an application-wide error logging facility that is completely pluggable." I recently added this to a project and it has become an invaluable tool. Really easy to use also :)